# In Itô calculus, what is the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am following Bernt Øksendal, Stochastic differential equations, 6.ed. Already in chapter 3, he talks about the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, but as far as I can tell, the set $\Omega$ and the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ has not been defined anywhere. Yet, the author states things such as “note that the filtration generated by the Brownian motion is contained in $\mathcal{F}$” on page 25. So, what is the definition of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$ in such textbooks? Is the idea that this space is the one obtained from the Kolmogorov extension theorem during the construction of the Brownian motion?

Comment: Is this not described in the earlier chapter (e.g. section 2.2)?

Comment: Are you saying that it is the space from Kolmogorov extension theorem?

Comment: Yes it is the space from the extension theorem.

Comment: See page 116 in the book Continuous Stochastic Calculus with Applications to Finance by M.Mayer or see page 60 in the book Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by S. Shreve.